# Windows Explorer Shell Extension for double click

Tags: windows, shell, registry, windows-explorer

Is there a way to change the default application that opens all files under specified directory on Windows Explorer double click event?

For other folders I want files to be opened by standard applications.

Comment: Short answer - no. Long answer - yes, if you create NSE you will be able to control all user actions include double click event. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#file As example you can see c:\Windows\Fonts folder

Answer (score 0):

Implement a [`IContextMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee453696(v=vs.85).aspx#static_implement_icontextmenu) shell extension. Register it under `HKCR\*\ShellEx` and add the [MayChangeDefaultMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee453696(v=vs.85).aspx#register_verb_handler) key to the CLSID registration.

You must create and register both a 32-bit and a 64-bit extension on 64-bit Windows.

When a file is double-clicked Explorer will load the extension and you can add a new default menu item if the file(s) in the dataobject fulfil your criteria. This will have a small system-wide performance impact.